# Can dual US-Canadian citizens travel to the US with an expired US passport but valid Canadian passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens

My kids are dual Canadian-US citizens and will be travelling from Israel to Canada via the US. If their US passport is expired (but their Canadian one is valid) can they travel on their Canadian passport, or will I need to renew the US passports to transit thru the US?

Answer (score 26):

Strictly speaking they need US passports to enter the US, which includes transit.  However, they will be able to board the plane with their Canadian passports since Canadian citizens require neither a visa nor ESTA.  Furthermore, US border officers cannot deny a US citizen entry to the US.

They can, however, delay entry, and if you encounter someone who is minded to make your life problematic for failing to use a valid US passport, they could delay you long enough to miss your flight.  It would be safer to renew the US passports before the flight.

For the return flight, if there is one, you will probably need US passports.  We had a report here of a US dual citizen who received ESTA authorization on her ESTA-eligible non-US passport even after disclosing her US citizenship on the ESTA application, but she seems to have been stopped at US preclearance in Canada, after having been issued a boarding pass.  She had to get a US passport and return later to undertake her journey.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100757/discussion-on-answer-by-phoog-can-dual-us-canadian-citizens-travel-to-the-us-wit).

Answer (score 5):

There are two parts to this question:

1. **Will they be allowed to enter the US?** Unlike, for example, European airports, North American airports don't have a transit area where you can move from gate to gate without going through immigration. So, your children *will* need to enter the US, even if just to leave again minutes later.
2. **Will they be allowed to board the plane?** The airline is responsible for checking whether a passenger will be allowed to enter the destination country. If the passenger is denied entry, the airline must transport them back *at their own cost* and in addition *pay a hefty fine*. Naturally, the airline wants to avoid both those things and thus will err on the side of caution. (Also, note that, should this happen, the airline will recover the costs from the passenger, i.e. your children.)

Re #1, it has been discussed multiple times on this site that US citizens *must* enter the US under their US nationality. Therefore, your children *must* enter the US as US citizens. Now, the good news is that being US citizens, they *must be admitted* into the country. However, the border control officer has every right (and duty) to make sure that they actually *are* US citizens … which they cannot prove. The officer cannot *deny* your children entry, but they can (and should!) do their due diligence and *delay* entry until they are sufficiently satisfied that your children are, in fact, US citizens.

Maybe the expired passports will be convincing enough, maybe not. Maybe, the US officer will ask a Canadian colleague to run the Canadian passports for some identifying information that they can use to look up your children in their system and convince themselves that they really are what they say they are. Maybe, they will require a long-form birth certificate.

Maybe, all of this will proceed fast enough for your children to catch their connecting flight, maybe not.

Re #2, the Canadian passport will *probably* be enough to convince the airline to let your children board. But, be aware that airlines use mostly automated systems to make this determination, and it could very well be the case that this automated system knows that your children are US citizens, that they are supposed to use their US passports and that those passports are expired. It is *too dangerous* for the airline to make any in-person determinations, or exceptions, or grant leniency. Also, the gate personnel are not trained immigration lawyers. They will rely on the automated systems *only*, and *there will be no discussions with them*, lest your children want to go through the experience of being dragged out of the airport by Israeli security personnel.

Unfortunately, this check is only made at the gate, since the airline cannot run the risk that something in the passenger's situation has changed between the time the tickets were bought and the time of boarding the plane. So, your children will only find out at the gate if they are allowed on the plane or not.

**tl;dr**: the safe route is to get new passports issued and use those to enter the US.

Comment: "However, the border control officer has every right (and duty) to make sure that they actually are US citizens … which they cannot prove." But they don't need to prove that they are US citizens. They are either US citizens or Canadian citizens, both of which can enter.

Comment: According to multiple questions on this site, US citizens *must* enter the US as US citizens. So, they are, in fact, not allowed to enter as Canadian citizens. They must enter as US citizens, and the border control officer must allow them to enter, because they are US citizens, but in order to do that, the border control officer needs to know that they are US citizens in the first place …

Comment: @user102008 There are two problems with entering as Canadian citizens. First, Canadian citizens are only admitted for six months and as tourists. Canadian citizens aren't allowed to go to school or work unless they have the proper visa. Second, as far as US law is concerned, they aren't Canadian citizens in the first place. When somebody has dual US/anything citizenship, the US considers them to be US citizens *only*. Of course, in practical terms, this situation probably wouldn't matter much.

Comment: @KevinKeane US law does not deny that they are Canadian citizens.  However, it does deny that they are aliens, because anyone who is a US citizen or national is by definition not an alien.  But that means that if they are admitted with a six month stamp in their Canadian passports that they can simply ignore it.

Comment: "If the passenger is denied entry, the airline must transport them back at their own cost and in addition pay a hefty fine": airlines are not fined for passengers who are denied entry for reasons th r airline could not have known about.  That's why airlines do not require criminal background checks of all their passengers.  Furthermore, if a Canadian citizen is denied entry to the US on a flight from some third country, the passenger will be sent off to Canada, not back to the third country.  If they're in transit to Canada they'll probably just be escorted to the flight in restraints.

Comment: "According to multiple questions on this site, US citizens *must* enter the US as US citizens." This is true - but there is no penalty for failing to do so.

Comment: Mechanistically, there's an interesting interaction where the border guard must acknowledge you are a US citizen to apply the "you must enter as a US citizen" requirement, and therefore must let you in... I wouldn't want to play those kind of cheeky games in real life though, I'd expect it to go poorly.

Comment: @mbrig if the border guard refuses to acknowledge the traveler's citizenship, they can either talk the traveler into withdrawing the application for admission, which requires sending the traveler off to another country, or detain the traveler for a hearing before an immigration judge.  Unless there's real reason to think the traveler is lying, the path of least resistance is simply to admit the person.  And in the face of passport records existing for the children in this case, there will be no real reason to think anyone is lying.

Comment: @phoog You are right, US law doesn't deny they are Canadian citizens as much as disregarding that fact. The end result is the same, though. In a different context, it may be clearer what that means: a dual US/Canadian citizen cannot demand Canadian consular assistance if he is arrested in the USA - even though a Canadian-only citizen can.

Comment: @KevinKeane yes, that's correct.  I know it may seem nitpicky, but I've heard the occasional anecdote of US officers refusing to accept a statement from a dual citizen that the person holds another citizenship, which is plainly absurd.  I've also heard people asserting that when a dual US-other citizen is in the US that person cannot show anyone their non-US passport, which is also absurd.  People make wildly different incorrect assumptions about the implications of the US "not recognizing" its citizens' other nationalities, up to and including that it means that dual nationality is forbidden.

Comment: @KevinKeane as to consular assistance, I don't know how it works in real life, but I imagine that while access to full consular assistance would probably not be provided, the consular authorities would normally be kept informed as a matter of courtesy, at least in some circumstances.

Comment: @phoog In practical terms, unfortunately, quite a few US states disregard their obligation to allow consular assistance even if somebody is *only* a foreign citizen. It has caused a number of diplomatic incidents over the years. But that's really a separate discussion.

Answer (score 3):

In a situation similar to yours, my wife (Finnish Passport) and I (US Passport) visited the US this past summer with our son (Finnish Passport and expired US Passport). We carried a photocopy of his expired US passport for easy reference if asked but used his non-expired Finnish passport for the airline and for the automated machine scan at border control in the US. We expected and were prepared to show and discuss his expired US Passport but we were not asked by the border agent.

I assume the computer and agent have access/knowledge of my son's previous entries and his US passport or that the information can easily be retrieved.

In all my experiences crossing the border by land from Canada or by air from other parts of the globe, every US Customs agent I have encountered has been intelligent, professional and focused on the job of protecting the US border (sometimes doing that with random or probing questions). Besides wanting to discuss it, I cannot picture that an individual agent would deny or restrict your entry or transit when your children have valid passports to travel with and their US citizenship is easily verified. Your children's' citizenship hasn't expired; just their documentation.

I would travel with their Canadian passports but take expired US passports (or copy) with you for reference if asked. Unless you have a reason not to, I would renew their US passports when you can since the future could be different.

(Note: I wanted to provide my experience on the issue but did not have enough reputation on 'Travel' to add this as a comment so added it as an answer instead)

Comment: I presume your son applied for and was granted ESTA authorization for the Finnish passport.  Did the application mention his US citizenship?

Comment: Our son, a US citizen, did not have ESTA. I'm not saying this is the correct way but my wife already had a previous valid ESTA and since he is a US citizen, we didn't think to apply for ESTA for him.

Comment: How did you get the airline to issue a boarding pass for your son without ESTA?

Answer (score 2):

### It's not just immigration.  It's the airline.

US-Canada flights are plentiful enough that you could simply get another flight if delayed by US Customs after physically landing in the US.  Heck,  a lot of US ports of entry are close enough you could just hop in a car and drive (e.g. JFK-Toronto).  **It's a bigger matter, however, if you are prevented from boarding in Israel**.

The airline will not fly you to a destination unless they are convinced you are eligible to enter the country.  They will refuse to allow you to board the plane.

There are a number of US infractions which are technically illegal, but with no penalty - like filing your taxes late when you don't owe any money.  While Customs will let you in after dispensing twenty lashes with a wet noodle, the airline view will be "it is not legal", *because if you somehow were refused, they have to pay the fine based on whether it is legal*.

Comment: he clearly states they have Canadian citizenship, so the airline would allow them to fly based on that.

Comment: @Aganju Did you catch the part about how they fly to the US and then to Canada? The US does not have transit zones, so they must enter the US.

Comment: @Harper I believe the point was that Canadian citizens are, in general, allowed to enter the US for transit without any documentation other than their Canadian passport. So an airline would not typically deny boarding to someone who shows a Canadian passport for a US-bound flight.

Comment: Airlines are not required to evaluate their passengers' admissibility.  They are required to ensure that they have the appropriate documents.  An airline who flies a Canadian felon to the US will not be fined if the person is denied entry on the basis of that felony conviction.  That is why airlines do not ask their passengers about their criminal records.

Comment: US immigration and customs will not stop you when you land in the US from Canada because you will have cleared immigration and customs in Canada prior to leaving the Canadian airport.

Comment: @user19474 but the trip in question is from Israel to Canada, with a layover in the US.  A passenger on such a trip will clear US immigration in the US, since there is no US preclearance in Israel.

Comment: @phoog You are correct. Replacing glasses now.

Answer (score 0):

***Hand over the Canadian passports, and mention that they are American citizens with expired U.S. passports.***

I can provide anecdotal evidence from the mirror opposite of this situation: I am dual US/Canadian, but have never held a Canadian passport (I have always meant to get around to applying, but never have). I went to university in Canada close to the U.S. border, and travelled between them by air and land multiple times per year.

Like the U.S., Canada also has a *de facto* requirement for citizens to enter on Canadian passports, but also similar to the U.S., Canada will not deny entry to its citizens. Usually, I just end up showing Canadian border officials a picture of my Canadian citizen certificate or SIN card on my phone, and they admit me without hassle, stamping my U.S. passport.

I imagine it would work similarly in your situation unless you get a particularly unkind agent.

Comment: But Canada's requirement is, as you note, *de facto.*  There is no law that makes it "unlawful" for a Canadian citizen to enter Canada without a Canadian passport. The US has such a law, so the requirement is *de jure.*  The situation is therefore not analogous.  In fact, Canada acknowledges that US-Canadian dual citizens can fly to Canada with their US passports because US citizens do not require eTA authorization to fly to Canada.  Before eTA, any Canadian dual citizen whose other country of nationality did not require a visa could fly to Canada with their other passport.

Answer (score -2):

Just only travel with the valid Canadian passports. The US immigration officers will just think they are Canadian and grant them entry.

Comment: This is false. US citizens *MUST* enter the US using their US passport. https://uk.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/u-s-passports/u-s-passport-faqs/u-s-citizenship/

Comment: While it might be true that "US immigration officers will just think they are Canadian," it also might not. They might be suspected to be US citizens if they were born in the US, which would be reflected on their Canadian passports, or if they are traveling with a US citizen parent. It is also possible that the Canadian passports might be linked to the US passport when the immigration officer scans the Canadian passport. It's a pretty easy match to make, since the names and dates of birth will match. I suppose the US probably doesn't actually do such matching, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: US Customs and Canada Customs share tons of information. Many times when entering US from Canada, custom officials have asked me "verification/identification" questions about my personal life in Canada that they had no way of knowing unless the Canadian government shared it with them.

Comment: @yms on the other hand, maybe they don't know the answers to those questions and are just probing to see whether your reason for crossing the border is legitimate.

Comment: @phoog the questions had nothing to do with the trip, it rather gave the impression that they were testing if I really was who I was claiming to be. Ex: you did part of your studies in Canada, which university was it? Or: you bought a property a few years back, which kind? when was it?

Comment: @yms that's creepy.  It reminds me a bit, though, of the kinds of questions one gets in the US when one's identity is being verified from a US credit report.  Perhaps the US officers are getting their data from some similar information source in Canada, whether through the Canadian government or not.